# How to speed up DOM update on grid

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is it possible to speed up the population of the grid? 
The following example takes about 20 seconds on an MBPro ( 2018 ).

I tried with queryselectorAll and getElementsByClass name but found no differences.

I tried put in an array the nodelist but without getting improvements.

```js
let div;
let cycles = 1000;
const min = 0;
const max = ( 54 * 40 ) - 1;

for ( let i = 0; i < max + 1; i++ ){
    div = document.createElement( "DIV" );
    div.classList = "grid-element";
    div.id = i;
    document.querySelector( ".grid-container" ).appendChild( div );
};

document.getElementById( "populate" ).addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    const cells = document.getElementsByClassName( "grid-element" );
    let start = new Date().getTime();
    function loop(){
        let cell = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) + min );
        if ( cells[ cell ].innerText === "" ) {
            cells[ cell ].innerText = 1;
        } else {
            cells[ cell ].innerText = parseInt( cells[ cell ].innerText ) + 1;
        };
        if( cycles != 0 ) {
            requestAnimationFrame( loop );
            cycles--;
        } else {
            alert( `Executed in ${ ( new Date().getTime() - start ) / 1000 } secs.` );
        };
    };
    requestAnimationFrame( loop );
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
    color: #ddd;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( 54, 1fr );
    background-color: #999;
    grid-gap: 1px;
}

.grid-element {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}   

.grid-element:before {
    content: "";
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button id="populate">Populate</button>
    <div class="grid-container"></div>
</body>
```

**Refactored code as *@fleau* suggested.**

```js
document.getElementById( "populate" ).addEventListener( 'click', () => {
        const cycles = 2500;
        const min = 0;
        const max = ( 54 * 40 ) - 1;
        const tab = [];
        const container = document.querySelector( ".grid-container" );
        container.innerHTML = "";

        for ( let i = 0; i < cycles; i++ ){
           const numb = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) + min );
           tab[numb] = typeof( tab[ numb ] ) === "number" ? tab[ numb ] + 1 : 1;
        };

        for ( i = 0; i < max + 1; i++ ){
            const div = document.createElement( "DIV" );
            div.innerText = typeof( tab[ i ] ) === "number" ? tab[ i ] : "";
            container.appendChild( div );
        };
   
});
```

```css
 .grid-container {
    color: #ddd;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat( 54, 1fr );
 background-color: #999;
 grid-gap: 1px;
}

.grid-container > div {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: #333;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 600;
} 

.grid-container > div:before {
 content: "";
 padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button id="populate">Populate</button>
    <div class="grid-container"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to change the user interface all the time, it's instantaneous if you don't do it. My code isn't clean but look when I do it without editing the user interface

```js
let div;
let cycles = 1000;
const min = 0;
const max = ( 54 * 40 ) - 1;


function cell() {
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * ( max - min + 1 ) + min );
}

function generateTable() {
    for ( let i = 0; i < max + 1; i++ ){
     div = document.createElement( "DIV" );
     div.classList = "grid-element";
     div.id = i;
     div.innerText = typeof(tab[i]) === "number" ? tab[i] + 1 : 1;
     document.querySelector( ".grid-container" ).appendChild( div );
 };
}

const tab = []

function loop(val){
    const numb = cell()
    tab[numb] = typeof(tab[numb]) === "number" ? tab[numb] + 1 : 1;
    if( val != 0 ) {
        loop(val-1);
    } else {
     generateTable();
        alert( `Executed in ${ ( new Date().getTime() - start ) / 1000 } secs.` );
    };
};


const start = new Date().getTime();
document.getElementById( "populate" ).addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    loop(cycles);
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
    color: #ddd;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat( 54, 1fr );
    background-color: #999;
    grid-gap: 1px;
}

.grid-element {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}   

.grid-element:before {
    content: "";
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button id="populate">Populate</button>
    <div class="grid-container"></div>
</body>
```